# Is it possible to add a flag icon using the Magento admin panel?

Tags: magento

Using magneto for my website and I need to display two different languagse. I have to set a flag icon for each location. One for English and one for Arabic. Is it possible to add a flag icon using the Magento admin panel, but not in root folder.

Answer (score 0):

> You should do it via template files.you will
>   have to write custom code for it.
>   Please refer to the example below:

```
<?php 
    foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name):   

    $current_currency_code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    if($current_currency_code == $_code) continue; 
    ?>
    <li class=" sel-cur" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">
        <a href="<?php echo $this -> getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code); ?>"   > <img class="pull-right" alt="<?php echo $_code; ?>" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl().'images/flags/img-'.$_code.'.jpg'?>"> </a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**OR**

You can Use extensions like

> Easy Flags

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-flags-module.html
You can customize it in your way.